# Client certificate is not sent to server despite being in server truststore

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, jsse

I am working in an environment with the following configuration.

- A Java server (outside my control) is hosting web services guarded by two-way SSL.
- The server truststore contains a specific certificate to trust, instead of an entire CA to trust.
- The specific certificate in question is a client certificate that I have access to.

In most cases, the application in question (e.g. SoapUI, Firefox, Chrome) won't send a client certificate to the server, despite one being installed in the local keystore or otherwise installed.

The only success I have had was with using Safari on my mac, as it allowed me to choose which client certificate I wanted to send.

Both the Client and and Server certificates are signed by the same CA, if that matters at all.

Is there any way to make this work without server-side changes?

Comment: So you have more than one client certificate in your keystore? Why?

Comment: Are you sure you put your client cert into client's keystore as opposed to client's truststore?

Comment: And are you sure the keystore contains a private-key entry with that alias?

Comment: @EJP I only have one client certificate in my Keystore.

Comment: @MichalFoksa Yeah I am sure that it is in my Client Keystore as opposed to my client truststore.

Comment: @EJP What do you mean by "that alias" ? I wasn't aware that the alias name mattered, but regardless I have tried every possible Alias name (the Subject CN of the certificate, the FQDN Url, etc.).

Comment: If you only have one certificate what is the meaning of 'allowed me to choose which client certificate'? The meaning of 'with that alias' is 'with the alias of the certificate'. I am wondering whether you have a private key, or just a certificate.